# How do I determine how many surprising shuffles/draws it will take to be confident a deck is not being randomly shuffled?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose a deck has forty cards. Repeatedly, I shuffle the deck, draw the top four cards, and record what those cards were. There are three copies of the Ace of Spades in the deck. Suppose the ace of spades appears in the first four cards every time. And I'm trying to decide whether I've just been really lucky, or there is something suspicious about the shuffle. (I'm actually thinking of an electronic game, not a physical shuffle, and the shuffling algorithm is unknown to me.)

How many times should I tolerate an ace of spades appearing in the top four drawn cards before I start to be quite confident the deck is not being shuffled totally randomly?

And how do I figure out the answer to that? I'd like to also figure this out for certain cards taht only appear once or twice in the deck for example.

Comment: What have you tried? Add some context about the problem, are you aware of probability theorems?

Comment: If you know just what's in the deck and decide in advance of the experiment what criterion you will use (e.g. Ace of Spades in the first four cards) then you can calculate the probability of that happening in each of the first $n$ shuffles. The probability will always be positive, so it can happen - unlikely things do happen all the time, at predictable rates. So you can never be "confident that the shuffle isn't random".

Comment: I know how to calculate the probability of it happening, but I'm not sure at what point I should say "this is low enough probability that I should definitely call shenanigans."

In the real-world situation I'm thinking about, I've had the card show up eight times in a row (and, by the way, it showed up as the _next_ card the other two times).

When I bring this up to other players they respond (as people tend to do in these discussions) by just saying "meh 10 is too small a sample size. Come back when you've done it a thousand times.) But I suspect this is already significant.

Comment: I know the probability of it happening eight times in a row is just around 1/66,666. I don't know whether this low probability, in itself, hits some kind of "significance threshold." I really don't know anything further than just how to calculate that probability. (And the probability of it happening eight times out of ten, rather than just eight in a row, I also don't know how to do.)

Comment: There is no answer to your question. There is the whole area in statistics called "hypothesis testing" (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) but the bottom line is that you up-front need to decide what's acceptable for you (acceptable probabilities of thinking the deck is rigged if it isn't, or vice versa). Statistics can then help you decide, based on those thresholds, what you should believe about the deck. However, it can't help you pick those thresholds, it's your job.